# [RIAK]InternalAPI-in-CommitHook

Tags: erlang, riak

I am new to erlang and riak.  I started to use riak as a kv store couple of months ago. Now i want to implement a commit hook to riak so that riak could help me to make some statistics.
i read some docs and write a pre-hook scripts, which will fetch the object key and store it into a set.
   This hook works fine if there is only one client write to riak, but if i increase the connection to riak writing, i found it lost some elements in the set. Looks like the crdt_op did not do the merge operation.And there is no obvious error in the log files.

Could someone help me to finger out what happened or what i has missed.

i am using the riak 2.1.3

Thanks all!

Here is the hook scripts:

---

```
-module(myhook).
-export([pretest/1]).

now_to_local_string({MegaSecs, Secs, MicroSecs}) ->
    LocalTime = calendar:now_to_local_time({MegaSecs, Secs, MicroSecs}),
    {{Year, Month, Day}, {Hour, Minute, _}} = LocalTime,
    TimeStr = lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~4..0w~2..0w~2..0w~2..0w~2..0w",
                [Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute])),
    TimeStr.

is_deleted(Object)->
    case dict:find(<<"X-Riak-Deleted">>,riak_object:get_metadata(Object)) of
        {ok,_} ->
            true;
        _ ->
            false
    end.

pretest(Object) ->
    % timer:sleep(10000),
    try
        ObjBucket = riak_object:bucket(Object),
  %     riak_object:bucket(Obj).

        Bucket = element(2, ObjBucket),
        BucketType = element(1, ObjBucket),

        ObjKey = riak_object:key(Object),
        % Key = binary_to_list(ObjKey),
        % ObjData = riak_object:get_value(Object),
        % Msg = binary_to_list(ObjData),
        CommitItem = iolist_to_binary(mochijson2:encode({struct, [{b, Bucket}, {k, ObjKey}, {t, BucketType}]})),

        case is_deleted(Object) of
            true ->
                KeyPrefix = "delete";
            _ ->
                KeyPrefix = "update"
        end,

        CurMin = now_to_local_string(os:timestamp()),
        IndexKey = binary:list_to_bin(io_lib:format("~s-~s", [CurMin, KeyPrefix])),

        %% Get a riak client
        {ok, C} = riak:local_client(),
        % get node obj
        ThisNode = atom_to_binary(node(), latin1),

        % get index obj and set context
        BType = <<"archive">>,
        B = <<"local-test">>,

        {SetObj, Context} = case C:get({BType, B}, IndexKey) of
            {error, notfound} -> 
                ThisSetObj = riak_kv_crdt:new({BType, B}, IndexKey, riak_dt_orswot),
                {ThisSetObj, undefined};
            {ok, ThisSetObj} ->
                % The datatype update requires the context if the value exists
                {{Ctx, _}, _} = riak_kv_crdt:value(ThisSetObj, riak_dt_orswot),
                {ThisSetObj, Ctx}
        end,

        UpdateIndex = [{add, CommitItem}],
        UpdateOp = {crdt_op, riak_dt_orswot, {update, UpdateIndex}, Context},
        % UpdateOp = {crdt_op, riak_dt_orswot, {update, UpdateIndex}, undefined},
        NewObj = riak_kv_crdt:update(SetObj, ThisNode, UpdateOp),

        error_logger:info_msg("Updating index for ~s,to set ~s~n", [binary:bin_to_list(CommitItem), IndexKey]),

        C:put(NewObj),
        Object
    catch
        error:Error ->
            {fail, lists:flatten(io_lib:format("[PREHOOKEXCEPTION]~p",[Error]))}
    end.
```

---

### This is the set bucket props

```
active: true
allow_mult: true
basic_quorum: false
big_vclock: 50
chash_keyfun: {riak_core_util,chash_std_keyfun}
claimant: 'riak@192.168.100.2'
datatype: set
dvv_enabled: true
dw: quorum
last_write_wins: false
linkfun: {modfun,riak_kv_wm_link_walker,mapreduce_linkfun}
n_val: 3
notfound_ok: true
old_vclock: 86400
postcommit: []
pr: 0
precommit: []
pw: 0
r: quorum
rw: quorum
small_vclock: 50
w: quorum
young_vclock: 20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your put `C:put(NewObj)` does not have the same options that Riak uses when dealing with CRDTs.

Riak KV uses this function to update a CRDT from a client request:

https://github.com/basho/riak_kv/blob/2.1.3/src/riak_kv_pb_crdt.erl#L162-L175

```
maybe_update({true, true}, Req, State0) ->
    #dtupdatereq{bucket=B, key=K, type=BType,
                 include_context=InclCtx,
                 context=Ctx} = Req,
    #state{client=C, mod=Mod, op=Op} = State0,
    {Key, ReturnKey} = get_key(K),
    O = riak_kv_crdt:new({BType, B}, Key, Mod),
    Options0 = make_options(Req),
    CrdtOp = make_operation(Mod, Op, Ctx),
    Options = [{crdt_op, CrdtOp},
               {retry_put_coordinator_failure, false}] ++ Options0,
    Resp =  C:put(O, Options),
    State = State0#state{return_key=ReturnKey, return_ctx=InclCtx},
    process_update_response(Resp, State);
```

Note that it explicitly passes `crdt_op` and `retry_put_coordinator_failure` options.

The record passed as the value of `crdt_op` is generated from this function:

```
make_operation(Mod, Op, Ctx) ->
    #crdt_op{mod=Mod, op=Op, ctx=Ctx}.
```

Comment: Thanks Joe， this problem was fixed by follow the code above, thanks alot